# Can´t create more than one row with a bidimensional arrayList

Tags: java, excel, arraylist

I have a code where I create an Excel introducing data from a bidimensional arrayList, and the data is taken with an scrapping method. The problem is that is not running as it should and I'm getting so desperate that I am starting think that I don't really know what I am doing.

I have read and find information on the net but none with this three steps (create a bidimensional arraylist, scrap data and create an excel with that information).

I hope there is another way, cause this is just a little training, the Excel I want to create has lots and lots of information. I would really appreciate some kind of help, I would like to understand but is obvious that I'm lost. I started learning java on the first of january my-self, and java arrays have nothing to do with PHP ones.

I don't even understand where I have to look at when I have a problem in java (I'm using eclipse).

Well here is the code I have created my self:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listaEmpresaA = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); //creation of the bidimensional array list.

    String [] paises = {"España", "USA", "Rusia"};

    int total_columnas = 2 + (paises.length*3);

    //Creating the columns
     for(int i =0; i< total_columnas; i++){
                listaEmpresaA.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            }

     //Creating the rows
     //Creating the header

     listaEmpresaA.get(0).add("Juego");
     listaEmpresaA.get(1).add("URL");



     for (int z=0 ; z<paises.length; z++) {
         for (int j=2; j<total_columnas ; j=j+3 ) {
             listaEmpresaA.get(j).add(paises[z]);
             listaEmpresaA.get(j+1).add(paises[z] + " Gold");
             listaEmpresaA.get(j+2).add(paises[z] + " sin Gold");
         }
     }

     //End of the header

     /*At this point if I write something like this          listaEmpresaA.get(1).add("URL"); should introduce that information below the first one, isn´t it? But that´s not happening...*/


    //From here just creating and introducing all the data in the excel.
     try {
         //create .xls and create a worksheet.
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\mierda.xls");
         HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("XboxOne");

         //Escribimos en el Excel toda la información
            int l=0;

                //Recorremos las filas
             for (int f=0; f< listaEmpresaA.get(0).size() ; f++) {
                HSSFRow fila = worksheet.createRow(f);

                //Recorremos las columnas
                for(int c=0;c<total_columnas;c++){
                       HSSFCell celda = fila.createCell(c);
                       celda.setCellValue(listaEmpresaA.get(c).get(f));
                       l++;

                }      
             }






        //Save the workbook in .xls file
         workbook.write(fos);
         fos.flush();
         fos.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

About the problem I have with the rows (that are not shown), I suppose that is because in the condicional I have just written `listaEmpresaA.get(0).size()` and I should count the number of rows I have.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I'm not sure what result you're trying to achieve, but you're only getting one row because `listaEmpresaA.get(0)` has only 1 value (Juego). As such, it loops only once, and then over 11 columns (total_columnas).

Comment: @Jaims Yes you are right, I solved that problem just including a new variable. I have improve a bit the code but I am working with the scrapping part. Just before creating the Excel. I'm using a for-each condicional to go from all the links (2.700 in total), but I have and error and I am running it again to see if I have solved the problem.